# ES6 push to static Array property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an ES6 class defined as such

```
const myMixin = (SomeOtherClass) => {
  class Something extends SomeOtherClass {
    static get __someProperty__() {
      return SomeOtherClass.__someProperty__ ? SomeOtherClass.__someProperty__.slice(0) : [ SomeOtherClass.name ];
    }
  }
...
```

Then, if I try to push a value into that array and then log its value, it remains the same.

```
Something.__someProperty__.push('someValue');
console.log(Something.__someProperty__);
//output: ['SomeOtherClass'], instead of ['SomeOtherClass', 'someValue']
```

I would have assumed that since the value of the property `__someProperty__` is an `Array` assigned at declaration, accessing it would always be a reference to the same structure and that there wouldn't be a problem pushing to it.  Am I missing something or getting something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: `Something.__someProperty__` is a getter that is reevaluated on every access, not "*an Array assigned at declaration*"?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Mutable static properties are an antipattern.

Comment: I should have specified that its a mixin.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Ok, but the question remains: why would you `push` to that array dynamically?

Comment: Basically as a way to keep track of the extension process the output class has been through by mixins.  Totally open to better ideas to reach that goal!

Comment: You could just traverse the prototype chain to get the class hierarchy. But even if you wanted to use a property, then should do the `push`ing inside the getter, e.g. `static get __someProperty__() {
      return ["Something", ...super.__someProperty__ || [super.name]]; }`

Comment: @Bergi it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it would always be a reference to the same structure

No you changed that. `Something.__someProperty__` evaluates to a new cloned array due to the `.slice(0)`.